# Qt multimedia gstreamer errors

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I just upgraded too ubuntu 16.10, and now I am having some problems with QtMultimedia 5.7.

I am getting the following errors when trying to access camera from qml.

```
(main:8542): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref_sink: assertion 'GST_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_bus: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_add_watch_full: assertion 'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_set_sync_handler: assertion 'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(main:8542): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_set_sync_handler: assertion 'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(main:8542): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

From what I have read this is a problem with ubuntu 16.10 dropping *gstreamer 0.10*. However trying to install gstreamer 0.10 has not resulted in any change.

When trying to play a video instead of accessing the camera I get the following error message:

```
Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/quicktime, variant=(string)iso'."
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."
```

Is there any tricks other than manually compiling Qt from source to work with gstreamer 1.0?

Comment: try with: libgstreamer-plugins-bad and gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

Comment: I already have gstreamer1.0-plugins-good and  libgstreamer-plugins-bad is not in the repositories.

Comment: @NatureShade , Have you solved the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Warning suggest you are missing **qtdemux** which is part of "gst-plugins-good"

Try, first below command to see if your missing qtdemux command.

`gst-inspect-1.0 qtdemux`